# Putting SSH keys I've taken from Ubuntu

Tags: security, ssh, unix

I came over to Mac from Ubuntu. I've saved all SSH files I had in the **.ssh** folder in Ubuntu. There are three files

- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub
- known_hosts

Is it possible to reuse these files in Mac? If so, where do I put them?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put them in the `~/.ssh/`
OS X uses the same OpenSSH package as every other unix.
Make sure you have set correct permissions, or ssh will not accept your keys

```
drwx------   5 user  staff   170 May 28 20:14 ./
-rw-------   1 user  staff  1679 May 19 14:19 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff   400 May 19 14:19 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff  6380 May 31 03:09 known_hosts
```

Comment: How do I set the permissions exactly like you, because I think I'm less restrictive than you in my permission set...?

Comment: `cd ~/.ssh ; chmod 700 . ; chmod 400 id_rsa ; chmod og-w *`